Vercel production mission css module class
I am working on a nextjs 14 project and I have a side by side view and when I tested the code locally using npm run dev, its working fine, the text is showing right and the media at left.
However, when I deployed the code to vercel production, there is something wrong with the way it is being rendered :-
The text seems to be stuck at start I don't know why, on inspecting I found out that its not able to have the css loaded for that particular text container.
&.isTextRight {
    .contentWrapper,
    .touts {
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        --text-content-start: calc(var(--grid-number-of-columns) / 2 + 4);
      }
    }

    .mediaContainer {
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        order: -1;

        --media-start: start;
        --media-width: calc(var(--grid-number-of-columns) / 2 + 1);

      }
    }

    .contentWrapper,
    .touts {
      @media (min-width: 1050px) {
        --text-content-start: calc(var(--grid-number-of-columns) / 2 + 3);
      }
    }

    .mediaContainer {
      @media (min-width: 1050px) {
        order: -1;

        --media-start: start;
        --media-width: calc(var(--grid-number-of-columns) / 2);

      }
    }
  }

This should be the css that should have been in effect for the text (contentWrapper)


